# activate function as a specific hour and then sleep for X time

Tags: c#

i am kinda new to c# to excuse me :)

what i try to accomplish is something like that,  i have 2x input paramaters from Console 
they are called

smallHour
bigHour

lets say smallHour = 2 and bigHour = 12,

now what i want to do it to activate a the function EVERY 2 hours and also EVERY 12 HOURS,
always at a round Hour at 00 minute. but when bigHour is activated smallHour should not run.

do u guys have any idie how i can do that?

the function they are activate is kind of "Reward" function hence why when the bigHour event happends it need to block to smallHour - so they wont get 2x rewards.

thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would have a console app taking in parameters for scheduling events. You would be better off setting up a scheduled task with those intervals.

Comment: becouse i want to let the user to decide every how much hours he want to activate the reward system

Comment: Perhaps you should provide some more details. What functions are they calling and why does the larger interval need to block the smaller one?

Comment: @Logarr: Why does it matter what it calls or why? You can just assume it calls methodA and methodB and let the OP worry about what those methods are...

Comment: Can the user enter fractions of an hour? So say, 1.5 for `smallHour`? And if so, how close to the `bigHour` do you want it to ignore the double rewards? (for example, users could enter fractions such that the `smallHour` tick occurs within 2 minutes of the `bigHour` tick)

Comment: users can only enter full hours for example each 2 or 3 or 4 hours etc so the bigHour and smallHour should big on same time

Answer (score 0):

.NET has a class called [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx).

One of the constructors I prefer to use is:

```
public Timer(
    TimerCallback callback,
    Object state,
    long dueTime,
    long period
)
```

When `dueTime` milliseconds have elapsed .NET will call the delegate `callback` with `state` as a parameter. Your callback implementation can use `DateTime.Now` to decide which function to call. The `period` determines the delay between successive calls.

Use this with care though, the timer callback will be called from a thread-pool thread. You may need to use locks to protect data structures from concurrent modification.